# MyBatis реализовать CRUD

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

Всем привет.

У меня есть PostgreSQL, к ней я подключаюсь посредством MyBatis.
вопрос, как мне реализовать стандартные crud операции create read update delete?

спасибо.

Comment: Написать код для каждой операции каждого маппера.

Comment: Получается 4 метода для четырех мапперов? к примеру для  <mapper>
    <delete id="delete" parameterType="Employee">
        DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = #{id}
    </delete>
</mapper>

Comment: По 4 запроса для каждой сущности. Для Employee 4, если будет какой-нибудь Customer, то ещё 4. И так далее.